# Conditionally selecting observations to sum across rows

Tags: r, conditional-statements, tidyverse, subset, logical-operators

Say I have a dataset that looks like:

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(var1_zscore = rnorm(100),
             var2_zscore = rnorm(100),
             var3_zscore = rnorm(100),
             var4_zscore = rnorm(100),
             var5_zcore = rnorm(100))
```

I want to sum across each row based on conditions that are specific to each variable. For instance, if var1_zscore is <= -1, then add the absolute value of var1_zscore to the row sum. If var2_zscore is <= -1 | >= 1, then add the absolute value of var2_zscore to the row sum. If var3_zscore is >= 1, then add the absolute value of var3_zscore to the row sum. If var4_zscore is >= 1, then add the absolute value of var4_zscore to the row sum. If var5_zscore is <= -1 | >= 1, then add the absolute value of var5_zscore to the row sum.

My desired output is a column called row_sum that has, for each row, the sum of the absolute values of columns var1_zscore : var5_zscore. For instance, the first row of data look like this:

| var1_zscore | var2_zscore | var3_zscore | var4_zscore | var5_zscore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -0.560475647 | -0.71040656 | 2.19881035 | -0.71524219 | -0.07355602 |

So the first row of data$row_sum would be 2.19881035.

I tried doing something like this:

```
data$row_sum<- rowSums(abs(data[,c((which(data$var1_zscore <= -1)),
                                    (which(data$var2_zscore <= -1 | data$var2_zscore >= 1)),
                                    (which(data$var3_zscore >= 1)),
                                    (which(data$var4_zscore >= 1)),
                                    (which(data$var5_zscore <= -1 | data$var5_zscore >= 1))
                                    )], na.rm = TRUE))
```

But I get ERROR: Can't subset columns past the end. (And then it tells me which locations in my data don't exist).

I think the problem is that I shouldn't be using the which function, but I'm not sure what else to use here? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: The logic behind `Et cetera` is not clear

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your desired output? Also, when using random generators (ie, `rnorm()`), please edit your question to include a seed (i.e., `set.seed(123)`)

Comment: @GuedesBF edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: @jpsmith edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: This will not solve your attempt, but it is worth noting that you have logical conditions that you are using to identify row numbers, using `which`. However, you are placing them in the *column* index location. For example, `iris[c(1,3),]` gets rows 1 and 3. Where as `iris[,c(1,3)]` gets columns 1 and 3. Notice where the comma is located. `iris[c(1,3), c(1,3)]` gets rows 1 and 3 as well as columns 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses `rowSums` on `across`:

```
library(dplyr)

name <- names(data)[endsWith(names(data), "zscore")]
lf <- list(
  \(x) ifelse({x} <= -1, abs({x}), 0),
  \(x) ifelse({x} <= -1 | {x} >= 1, abs({x}), 0),
  \(x) ifelse({x} >= 1, abs({x}), 0),
  \(x) ifelse({x} >= 1, abs({x}), 0),
  \(x) ifelse({x} <= -1 | {x} >= 1, abs({x}), 0)
) %>% 
  setNames(name)

data %>% 
  mutate(row_sums = rowSums(across(all_of(name), ~ lf[[cur_column()]](.))),
         # add additional variables to sum
         addl_sums = rowSums(pick(c(row_sums, other_numeric1:numeric_variable))))
```

`across` applies a different function to each column that is set via `lf` and called using `cur_column()`. The output of `across` is a data frame of these columns with the functions applied. Then we simply take the row sums.

*Update*

To add additional variables you can use any number of [tidy-select](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) helpers within the `pick` verb. Here I used the range feature (`:`) to select consecutive columns. However you could have done:

- `row_sums | (contains("numeric") & where(is.numeric))`
- `c(row_sums, numeric_variable) | matches("numeric\\d$")`

And so forth.

**Output**

```
     var1_zscore var2_zscore var3_zscore var4_zscore  var5_zcore row_sums
1   -0.560475647 -0.71040656  2.19881035 -0.71524219 -0.07355602 2.198810
2   -0.230177489  0.25688371  1.31241298 -0.75268897 -1.16865142 2.481064
3    1.558708314 -0.24669188 -0.26514506 -0.93853870 -0.63474826 0.000000
4    0.070508391 -0.34754260  0.54319406 -1.05251328 -0.02884155 0.000000
5    0.129287735 -0.95161857 -0.41433995 -0.43715953  0.67069597 0.000000
6    1.715064987 -0.04502772 -0.47624689  0.33117917 -1.65054654 1.650547
7    0.460916206 -0.78490447 -0.78860284 -2.01421050 -0.34975424 0.000000
8   -1.265061235 -1.66794194 -0.59461727  0.21198043  0.75640644 2.933003
9   -0.686852852 -0.38022652  1.65090747  1.23667505 -0.53880916 2.887583
10  -0.445661970  0.91899661 -0.05402813  2.03757402  0.22729192 2.037574
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
  other_nonnumeric = sample(letters, 100, replace = T),
  var1_zscore = rnorm(100),
  var2_zscore = rnorm(100),
  var3_zscore = rnorm(100),
  var4_zscore = rnorm(100),
  var5_zcore = rnorm(100),
  other_numeric1 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = T),
  other_numeric2 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = T),
  numeric_variable = sample(0:1, 100, replace = T)
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One other thing: for brevity in my post, I removed about ~20 variables that precede my z-score variables. These variables do not need to be summed (they are mostly character or categorical variables) but must be retained in the resulting dataset. How would you edit this line so that it doesn't mutate across all my variables, just the ones that end in 'zscore' ?    data %>% mutate(row_sums = rowSums(across(all_of(names(lf)), ~ lf[[cur_column()]](.))))

Comment: @burphound Yes, no problem. I have updated my answer with these changes. I just created a vector of column names that contain the columns you want to sum: `name`.

Comment: Thank you SO much. Sorry to bother you with one last thing. I have 5 other variables whose names do not end in 'z-score' and I want to add them to the rowsum as well. Each of those columns contains values that are either 1 or 0. How would you adapt the mutate() call to include those columns?

Comment: @burphound I have updated my answer with an edited `mutate` statement. Please note that I also updated the **Data** section with a reprex data frame.

Answer (score 2):

We can create a logical index of values to consider in the rowSums, replacing values to be ignored with 0 beforehand.
First create a list of conditions.
Then loop over the columns and the list of conditions pair-wise with `mapply` or `purrr::map2` to create the index.
Finally, perform the `rowSums` on a data.frame with the ignored values replaced by 0, inside the call to `mutate`.

```
library(purrr)

#list of conditions:
conditions  <- list(\(x) x <= -1,
                    \(x) x <= -1 | x >= 1,
                    \(x) x >= 1,
                    \(x) x >= 1,
                    \(x) x <= -1 | x >= 1)

#create logical index:
index <- map2(data, conditions, ~.y(.x))

#create column with rowsums of logically indexed cells:
data |>
    mutate(sums = 
               map2_dfc(abs(data),
                        index,
                        ~ifelse(.y,
                                .x,
                                0
                                )
                        ) |>
               rowSums()
           ) |>
    head(10)

   var1_zscore var2_zscore var3_zscore var4_zscore  var5_zcore     sums
1  -0.56047565 -0.71040656  2.19881035  -0.7152422 -0.07355602 2.198810
2  -0.23017749  0.25688371  1.31241298  -0.7526890 -1.16865142 2.481064
3   1.55870831 -0.24669188 -0.26514506  -0.9385387 -0.63474826 0.000000
4   0.07050839 -0.34754260  0.54319406  -1.0525133 -0.02884155 0.000000
5   0.12928774 -0.95161857 -0.41433995  -0.4371595  0.67069597 0.000000
6   1.71506499 -0.04502772 -0.47624689   0.3311792 -1.65054654 1.650547
7   0.46091621 -0.78490447 -0.78860284  -2.0142105 -0.34975424 0.000000
8  -1.26506123 -1.66794194 -0.59461727   0.2119804  0.75640644 2.933003
9  -0.68685285 -0.38022652  1.65090747   1.2366750 -0.53880916 2.887583
10 -0.44566197  0.91899661 -0.05402813   2.0375740  0.22729192 2.037574
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this seems so close but the "sums" value for the first row should be 2.19881035. Do you know what is happening there to get 2.059680?

Comment: I do not get the reason for the diference too. At first I had a wrong condition for Var5_zscore, but I corrected it

Comment: Is it the seed you set? Is the OP using 123 and you might be using 1?

Comment: I corrected it to use 123 but keep getting an inaccurate result. Very weird, the code looks just fine, It is pretty much the same strategy as yours, lmc

Comment: Ah, it is your conditional statement. If you have the yes/no flipped: `ifelse(.y, .x, 0)`

Comment: oh, that was it. I needle in a haysack, as always! It is fine now. Thank you, @LMc