# Conditionally perform an action in one dataset based on a second dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
set.seed(123)
season <- c('spring', 'autumn')
data <- data.frame(id = seq(1:300),
             season = sample(season, 300, replace = TRUE), # using this as an example of extra_col_1
             weight = rnorm(300, 200, 100), # using this as an example of extra_col_2
             group = sample(1:8, 300, replace = TRUE),
             albumin = rnorm(300, 5, 3),
             cortisol = rnorm(300, 20, 12),
             calcium = rnorm(300, 6, 0.05))
```

There are 8 groups of participants and a total of 300 observations. Each group has a 'true' reference range, and I want to compare each observed value for albumin, cortisol, and calcium to its group-specific reference range.

The reference range data look like this (note these are fake data):

```
set.seed(123)
reference <- data.frame(group = c(1:8),
                    albumin_lower_limit = rnorm(8, 4.6, 0.3),
                    albumin_mean = rnorm(8, 4.7, 0.3),
                    albumin_sd = rnorm(8, 0.3, 0.01),
                    albumin_upper_limit = rnorm(8, 7.5, 0.3),
                    cortisol_lower_limit = rnorm(8, 7.6, 1.3),
                    cortisol_mean = rnorm(8, 11.8, 1.3),
                    cortisol_sd = rnorm(8, 1.3, 0.01),
                    cortisol_upper_limit = rnorm(8, 16.4, 1.3),
                    calcium_lower_limit = rnorm(8, 8.9, 0.05),
                    calcium_mean = rnorm(8, 9.4, 0.05),
                    calcium_sd = rnorm(8, 0.05, 0.01),
                    calcium_upper_limit = rnorm(8, 11.9, 0.05))
```

I'm trying to write code that says, for each group, if an observation is outside of its reference range (ie, if an observation is lower than the lower limit, or higher than the upper limit), then take the z-score of that observation using the reference mean and standard deviation.

For example: one individual in group 8 has an albumin of 8.22 (see data[1,] ). Since 8.22 is outside of group 2's albumin reference range (see reference[8,] ), then I want to calculate the z-score of 8.22 using the group 8 albumin mean and SD (which are 4.86 and 0.30, respectively).

Equation for z-score:  z = ( x - mean ) / sd

My desired output is a column of z-score values, e.g., data$zscore

Example of desired output:

| id | season | weight | group | albumin | cortisol | calcium | albumin_zscore | cortisol_zscore | calcium_zscore | result |

|---|--------|------------|---|-----------|----------|---------|---------|--------|---|---|

|1  | spring | 278.77388  | 8 |  8.2220368| 7.8306299| 6.030993| 11.32313| |-3.704291| -74.68739 | -67.06855|

The -67.06855 is the result of adding the z-scores for albumin, cortisol, and calcium, because the value for each of these is outside of its respective reference ranges. If only albumin and cortisol had values outside of their respective reference ranges, then the 'result' would include only the sum of t the z-scores for albumin and cortisol.

Note, I have about 20 variables, 1100 observations, and 8 groups for which I need to calculate group-specific z-scores, so automating this would be time saving. I understand how I would do this for each group and variable combination, but I am stuck as to how to do it en mass and get it into one column.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Easier if you reshape. First we make the reference columns show each chemical in one row and each stat in one column.

```
library(tidyverse)

ref_long <- reference %>%
  pivot_longer(-group, names_to = c("substance", "stat"),
               names_pattern = "(.*?)_(.*)") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = stat, values_from = value)
```

Then we can make the data long, pull in the reference data, do our z calcs within each group, then produce a result depending on if the data is out of range.

```
data %>%
  pivot_longer(-group, names_to = "substance") %>%
  left_join(ref_long) %>%
  group_by(group, substance) %>%
  mutate(z_calc = (value - mean(value))/sd(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(z_calc_ref = (value - mean)/sd,
         result = if_else(value < lower_limit |
                            value > upper_limit,
                          z_calc_ref,
                          z_calc))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The only thing is, I have about ~50 other columns (a mix of character and integer columns) that I omitted from my question for brevity, but I would like to retain these columns in my final dataframe . When I run the second half of the code (data %>% pivot_longer) I get an error 'Can't combine `extra_col_1` <character> and `extra_col_2` <integer>.' I assume this is because R doesn't know what to do with the rest of my columns? Is there a way to make this code friendly so that it can retain the other columns?

Comment: Another thing I realize I omitted: in 'data', each row has a unique id. I want the final dataset to retain the number of rows in 'data' and the data$result column to be, for each row, a sum of all z-scores where the value was outside of the reference range. I will edit my question now to better convey that.

Comment: I'm sure that could be done by `select(-c(COLUMNS:TO_EXCLUDE))` to leave those columns out of the pivot, and then use `left_join(data %>% select(c(COLUMNS:TO_EXCLUDE)), by = "id")` to bring them back in at the end. I can look at this again tomorrow. I'm not sure the most elegant way to deal with this since it sounds like your table is fundamentally two kinds of data -- one that is a substance-stat pairing, and a bunch of other mystery columns that relate to the `id`.

Comment: @LMc do you have ideas as to how you might do this?

Comment: Thank you so much. TBH, retaining the mystery columns is a minor feature, having the right data$result column is my main goal. LMc gave a great solution to a similar question I had - link below in case it jogs ideas. I've been playing around with this code on my end to see if I can adapt it to my current question. The main difference between that code and this one is that here, I'm working with two datasets instead of one.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76095765/conditionally-selecting-observations-to-sum-across-rows/76096013?noredirect=1#comment134202567_76096013

Comment: I think it would be appropriate for you to try my suggestion and see if you hit an obstacle you can't overcome. BTW, I would discourage adding elements (even if they're not new to you) into a question after it has been answered, or tagging other people to solicit help for a question. I think this forum works best when people can freely give their time to assist in specific problems, without the expectation that they will be "on call" to answer followups.